# Audio distorted when connecting to bluetooth using AVPlayer on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, audio, bluetooth, avplayer

I've been trying to reproduce the audio of a video on the Bluetooth speakers and the audio gets distorted ever with the volume being quite low. The video is reproduced with AVPlayer and the sounds are correct when it plays on the device on iOS 13
Following some of the comments I've seen during my research I added the code:

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowBluetooth, .allowBluetoothA2DP,.defaultToSpeaker])
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            
} catch(let error) {
    print("*** \(error) ***")
    Crashlytics.crashlytics().record(error: error)
}
```

I tried with the previous code in a different place, before the initialization of AVPlayer, after the initialization or in the AppDelegate with the same result.

Some related questions:

[How to connect the audio to bluetooth when playing using AVPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133636/how-to-connect-the-audio-to-bluetooth-when-playing-using-avplayer)

[iOS Swift - Poor audio quality when using Bluetooth external speaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947490/ios-swift-poor-audio-quality-when-using-bluetooth-external-speaker)

[AVAudioSession setCategory Swift 4.2 iOS 12 - Play Sound on Silent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51010390/avaudiosession-setcategory-swift-4-2-ios-12-play-sound-on-silent)

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove the `.allowBluetooth`  category and use `.allowBluetoothA2DP` instead. You shouldn't have both. This should fix any audio distortion you are having.

The `allowBluetooth` category uses *HFP* (Hands-Free Profile) protocol, which is low quality and usually meant for phone calls.

The `allowBluetoothA2DP` category, on the other hand, is **output only**. and intended for **higher bandwidth audio use cases**. See to Apple's docs:

> A2DP is a stereo, output-only profile intended for higher bandwidth audio use cases, such as music playback.

Sources:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/categoryoptions/1771735-allowbluetootha2dp

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/categoryoptions/1616518-allowbluetooth